# Rewrite my jsp page based on url

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0

> I need to rewrite my page based on url in web.xml. I tried following , it throws 404 .

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>accountActivation</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/jsp/accountActivation.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>accountActivation</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/accountActivation</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

> Is there any jar file needed for this, or any filter for redirect suggest me. I am struck with this . I am using jsp and servlet.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error finding the proper .jsp file, provide the proper location in jsp-file tag.